# Installing Ubuntu via Boot Camp on 1st gen Macbook running Lion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, unix

Does anyone know if it's possible to install Ubuntu via bootcamp on a first gen Macbook running Lion? I'd prefer not to use Parallels/VMware due to the fact that it's only got 1GB of RAM in it and I'd prefer not to upgrade it.

Comment: Only 1GB of RAM? Do you not find Lion painfully slow? The minimum spec is 2GB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Boot Camp steps

1. Download Windows drivers for your Mac.
2. Partition your hard drive to make space for Windows.
3. Sets your Mac to default boot into Windows after installation.

None of these options will help you  with your Ubuntu installation except for the partitioning. But this can also be done using Disk Utility. Therefore, I recommend using Disk Utility to change your partition scheme. This will also take care moving your `Recovery HD` partition (which GParted on the LiveCD will not do that easily).

#### Easiest Ubuntu Install

1. Using Disk Utility, add a second "partition" and make that **free space**.
2. During the Ubuntu installation process choose to install Ubuntu next to the Mac OS. This will also automatically partition the free space for your needs.
3. Install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) to sync the partition tables.

#### Further options

- creating a file exchange partition for Ubuntu and MacOSX
- manually formatting the free space using the LiveCD in order to create a separate `/home` directory

Comment: I've heard rumors that Apple's BootCamp software works fine for installing Ubuntu in exactly the same way it installs Windows, no rEFIt needed, is that not true?

Comment: There really is not need to use BootCamp to install Ubuntu. Yes, you can boot into Windows/Ubuntu without rEFIt. You can select which partition to boot from by holding alt during boot.